# JavaFX WebView parsing HTML if read from .txt file

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Came to a situation, when I need to read from an external module\script, which generates HTML code and stores it into a .txt file(and I don't have influence on that module).

I formed a regular WebView and try to pass to it's WebEngine the path to that file in a manner:

> webNode.getEngine().load(new
>   File("c:/somefile.txt").toURI().toString());

But the output is a raw text with html tags, without being parsed(the HTML is kinda messy and I think that some point may not even be closed properly, but don't think this may have influence).

I know there is a second option to load HTML using 'loadContent', but until this is needed, I would like to bypass manually reading the file and passing it's internals using that method.

So the question is: is there a possibility to force the parsing in case of using the 'load'(or some pointers on another way to resolve this).

Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation, you are either loading a URL or the String content. I'm not sure why you are avoiding loadContent. That seems to be your best bet.

Comment: I understand that loadContent can be used. But in the scope of the task when i'm nor reading a single already made html file, but reading across multiple large files, which are updated in the process of reading them and need cache and per event update, gives me the idea that 'loadContent' solution will come to a out of memory exception.